# jQuery $.post Callback Function (data) is Undefined

Tags: php, jquery, post, callback

I submit a form using jQuery to a php file on my server.
Everything works... (the php file gets the right post variables, makes a database entry etc.)
But on the response, sometimes 'data' goes wacky.

```
$('#form_submit').click( function() {
    $.post("path/to/script.php", $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
        if ( data.status == 1 ) {
            alert('awesome sauce');
        } else {
            alert('crap');
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

php script returns (on success)

```
$response['status'] = 1;
$response['message'] = 'worked';
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

I'm getting a whole lot of crap, and not enough awesome sauce.

Does anyone have an idea why sometimes 'data.status' is undefined, and sometimes it isn't?

Comment: Maybe things go wrong in your PHP script. There is not really enough information to give a proper suggestion.

Comment: i'm using chrome. the thing that gets me is that i'll go grab a cup of coffee, come back and reload the page, and all of a sudden it'll work.

Comment: have you tried `console.debug(data)` ? This may provide insight into what you get at the times when you don't have `data.status`. Also, check the "network" tab, in chrome.

Comment: Felix, that's definitely enough info code wise.

Comment: i'll try that Will... and i've tried: {"status":1,"message":"worked"} ... WTF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this>

```
$('#form_submit').click( function() {
$.post("path/to/script.php", $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if ( obj.status == 1 ) {
        alert('awesome sauce');
    } else {
        alert('crap');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: yep I've checked that too but it seems that $.post is converting the JSON output directly to javascript object when it triggers the success event as they wrote in their API docs. (the second example from bottom in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: so the question i've got then... why is the data parsed correctly by jquery, and sometimes not. (when not using `jQuery.parseJSON(data);`)

Comment: i had same problems a day ago with json data and this part: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` helped me

Comment: helped me too, but the unreliability of the other way of doing things is bothering me

Comment: yes i have debuged it long hours googled and etc. so i am happy now that is working and glad to help you too

Comment: You can explicitly pass in the *dataType* parameter to *post()*; it may be that jQuery is simply not guessing the expected return type properly.

Comment: dyoo i didnt knowed that. i knew that with the `$.ajax();` method it is possible but did not find that in the jquery documentation

Comment: Try it; the comments near the middle and bottom of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ suggest that if the web server isn't responding with a particular response type, then jQuery may not guess that the string it's getting back should be treated as a JSON-encoded response.  Better not to have it guess.

Comment: dyoo... i realize in my example code i forgot to type the trailing ` ... "json");`, but it is included in my actual code, so i'm editing the post to reflect that.

Comment: Darn.  I was hoping it would be an easy explanation.  :)

Answer (score 2):

How does *exit()* behave with regards to output buffering?  Does it flush the output buffer?

Comment: good question, but this seems to be more of a an issue on the jquery end.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$('#form_submit').click( function() {
    $.post("path/to/script.php", $('#form').serialize())
     .success(function(){
        alert('awesome sauce');
     }).error(function(){
        alert('crap');
     });
});
```

Comment: yeah, that'll give me a workaround here where i'm guaranteeing that there's a success database-wise (data.status=1), but what if that fails (data.status=0)? this isn't reliable.